# Handle HTTP Header Field name on iOS/OSX

Tags: ios, macos, asihttprequest, restkit, afnetworking

As we know HTTP header names are case insensitive which is specified in [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

However I found that all popular iOS/OSX framework such as [ASIHTTRequest](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request) , [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) ,[RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) test whether or not a header field exists using following code.

```
[[self responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"Keep-Alive"];
[[self responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"Content-Length"];
```

the responseHeaders is just an NSDictionary. I had thought CFNetwork layer would handle this however no clues found. Maybe this is a convention in real world?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, the `-[NSHTTPURLResponse allHeaderFields]` method returns a case insensitive NSDictionary instance. This has nothing to do with the `_CFCapitalizeHeader` function which has been removed in recent versions of CFNetwork. Unfortunately its source code is not available anymore.

Here is a simplified call graph of the `allHeaderFields` method (OS X 10.8.3)

```
-[NSHTTPURLResponse allHeaderFields] -- Foundation
    CFHTTPMessageCopyAllHeaderFields() -- CFNetwork
        HTTPMessage::copyAllHeaderFields(__CFArray const**)
            MixedDict::copyAsOrdinaryDict(__CFAllocator const*, __CFArray const**) const
                CFDictionaryCreateMutable()
```

This dictionary is eventually returned as the result of the `allHeaderFields` method. Here is what the [third parameter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CFDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFDictionaryKeyCallBacks) passed to `CFDictionaryCreateMutable` looks like:

```
version = 0
retain = _keyRetain(__CFAllocator const*, void const*) // __ZL10_keyRetainPK13__CFAllocatorPKv
release = _keyRelease(__CFAllocator const*, void const*) // __ZL11_keyReleasePK13__CFAllocatorPKv
copyDescription = _keyCopyDescription(void const*) // __ZL19_keyCopyDescriptionPKv
equal = _keyEqual(void const*, void const*) // __ZL9_keyEqualPKvS0_
hash = _keyHash(void const*) // __ZL8_keyHashPKv
```

The `_keyEqual` C++ method eventually calls `CFStringCompare` with the `kCFCompareCaseInsensitive` option.

This is why not caring about case sensitivity of NSHTTPURLResponse headers works.

It is very unfortunate that this behavior is not documented, though. Please dupe radar [#13715902](http://www.openradar.me/13715902) asking for documentation.

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest use CFNetwork function instead of NSHTTPURLResponse. Maybe my answer explain this case. And your answer explain AFNetworking case, right ?

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest uses [`CFHTTPMessageCopyAllHeaderFields`](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/blob/v1.8.1/Classes/ASIHTTPRequest.m#L2135) which is the same function used by `-[NSHTTPURLResponse allHeaderFields]` internally. So my answer applies to ASIHTTPRequest as well. And since the `_CFCapitalizeHeader` function has been removed from CFNetwork, your answer can not apply at all.

Comment: I use "nm" to print iOS 6.1 SDK's CFNetwork's symbols and do not find CFCapitalizeHeader. You're right ! It has be removed. However to improve your answer, could you specify from which version Apple remove __CFCapitalizeHeader ? And +1 for Apple to improve its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer. Although there are no documentation about this. CFNetwork layer did normalize the header field.  http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-129.9/HTTP/CFHTTPMessage.c  the work is done in function __CFCapitalizeHeader.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following code in my app to get the last modified date from the server

```
lastModifiedStringFromServer = [[responseForDateFromServer allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"];
```

The header fields and its values are in the NSDictionary format. Therefore we have to use objectForKey to obtain the value.

Comment: Premsuraj,I don't think you understand my question.